Awesome_Snackbar_Content Swipe to dismis
How to swipe Awesome_Snackbar_Content to dismis
enter image description here
final snackBar = SnackBar(
                  /// need to set following properties for best effect of awesome_snackbar_content
                  elevation: 0,
                  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  content: AwesomeSnackbarContent(
                    title: 'On Snap!',
                    message:
                        'This is an example error message that will be shown in the body of snackbar!',

                    /// change contentType to ContentType.success, ContentType.warning or ContentType.help for variants
                    contentType: ContentType.failure,
                  ),
                );

                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                  ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
                  ..showSnackBar(snackBar);
              },
            ),


void showSnackbar(context) {
  Scaffold.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        dismissDirection: DismissDirection.none,
        content: Text("I am here"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ))
  );
}

I hope someone can solve this problem
enter image description here

Try swipe to dismiss for a Snackbar with Dismissible like below
final snackBarCustom = SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            content: Dismissible(
              key: UniqueKey(),
              direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('Awesome Snackbar Content'),
              ),
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
              },
            ),
          );
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBarCustom);

